# What is the type of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation:

$$\left( \frac 1x - \frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2} \right)\, dx = \left( \frac 1y - \frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2} \right)\, dy$$

I can't determine a type of this equation. Perhaps, this is equations in total differentials, but I сan't find an integrating multiplier. Help please.

Comment: WolframAlpha says it is a ["first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427el6p1u682dc)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

To see that it is an exact differential lets:

$$
P(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{y^2}{(x-y)^2} \qquad Q(x,y)=\dfrac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}-\dfrac{1}{y}
$$
and you can see that $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$

The solution of your equation is $f(x,y)=C$ where $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=P(x,y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=Q(x,y)$.

You can find $f(x,y)$ in the standard way ( [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation#Solutions_to_exact_differential_equations) ) and find:

> $$ f(x,y)= \log x- \log y +\dfrac{xy}{x-y} $$

Comment: Why dP/dy = dQ/dx ? How did you get your solution ? With WolframAlpha?

Comment: If you calculate the derivative you find: $ \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=-\dfrac{2xy}{(x-y)^3}$. This suggested to me to test a function of the form $f(x,y)=a\log x +b \log y + c\dfrac{xy}{x-y}$. I suppose that W|A do something similar. Anyway,  if you integrate $P$ with respect to x you find a function $f(x,y)=\log x+\dfrac{y^2}{x-y}+g(y)$, than if you derive this with respect to $y$ and substitute for $Q$ you find the result - this is the standard way :)

Answer (score 2):

Another method is suggested in observing the symetry relatively to $x$ and $y$.

The change of variable $t=\frac{x}{y}$ transforms the ODE into a linear ODE 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}-\frac{y}{t(t-1)} = -\frac{t-1}{t^2}$$
Solving this ODE and bringing back $t=\frac{x}{y}$ into the result leads to the solution on the implicit form :
$$\frac{xy}{x-y}+\ln\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|=\text{constant}$$.